# Problems with sendSubviewToBack and insertSubview:belowSubview: don't work as they should

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a problem with `sendSubviewToBack` and `insertSubview:belowSubview:` methods. Simply, I have a button which I'm inserting below another view `_centerView`. I want the button to stay below the `_centerView`.

The problem I'm facing is that when I insert a button below the `_centerView` I see a flicker (just for a short moment) over the `_centerView`. I tried both `sendSubviewToBack:` and `insertSubview:belowSubview:` - same effect.

Do you have any ideas what things may be wrong? Am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
    UIButton* itemButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [itemButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [itemButton setCenter:_centerView.center];

    [parentView bringSubviewToFront:_centerView];
    [parentView insertSubview:itemButton belowSubview:_centerView];
```

Comment: ..and what happens when you remove `bringSubviewToFront:` ?

Comment: @skram nothing, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a while it turned out that this is the fault of the window I animated the same time I added the button. I don't know why but the fade in animation of the window was causing this problem. I switched of the animations of my UIWindow and now it works. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this same issue, but passing this option to the animation code fixed it. Hopefully this is helpful to you too. I wouldn't have come up with my solution without your comment though, so thanks for that :)

```
UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the internal structure behind `insertSubview` is, but if you want to get rid of the flicker, the easiest way would be to hide the view before inserting it and show it again afterwards.

```
[itemButton setHidden:YES];
[parentView insertSubview:itemButton belowSubview:_centerView];
[itemButton setHidden:NO];
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Hmm. If you take out the `[itemButton setHidden:NO];` line, does it still flicker? If not, you may need to just keep it hidden until it is time for it to appear from behind _centerView. I can't get this problem to reproduce on my device, though, so I'm not sure if that will help, either.